# How to use MAX() for multiple occurrences of Max values in SQL

Tags: sql, max

Does the MAX() function return just the first occurrence of the maximum value it encounters? What happens if there are multiple occurrences across different rows of the same max value? Is there a way to get all these rows using the MAX() function? Please help!

Comment: MAX() returns a value, so it doesn't matter how many rows have that value, do you mean you what to find all rows containing value = max(value)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`MAX()` is a scalar function returns a single value and not records so if you have multiple records that have the same value which is maximum, the following will still return only one value:

```
SELECT MAX(Value) FROM MyTable
```

If you want to get all records that have the maximum value, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: I've tried in the where clause by using `where Value = MAX(Value)` but it generates error, could you please explain a little bit why we cannot be lazy here but have to use a sub clause `WHERE Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM MyTable)`?

Comment: you have to use `having` clause with aggregate functions